# getting Python variable name in runtime

Tags: python

This is different from retrieving variable/object name at run time.

```
2G_Functions={'2G_1':2G_f1,'2G_2':2G_f2}
3G_Functions={'3G_1':3G_f1,'3G_2':3G_f2}
myFunctionMap=[2G_Functions,3G_Functions]
for i in myFunctionMap:
    print i.??? "\n"
    for j in i:
            print str(j)
```

I want the output look like below.

```
2G_Functions:

2G_1

2G_2

3G_Functions:

3G_1

3G_2
```

How can I get the name of dictionary variable in my code?I dont know which I am calling in the loop to know its name beforehand.

Comment: The variables in your code are not valid identifiers. Run the first line in Python's interactive mode and you'll get a syntax error right away. Please test for things like this before submitting questions, as it makes it much more difficult for people to help you.

Comment: Sorry for that.I was intending to put a pseudocode instead of real code.

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732955/python-how-to-get-arguments-name-runtime/16733435?noredirect=1#16733435) as another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't. The `myFunctionMap` list contains the objects, not the name attached to them 2 lines above. BTW, calling a list variable "map" isn't a good practice, maps are usually dictionaries.
2. You can't start a variable name with a digit, so `2G_Functions` and `3G_Functions` won't work.
3. You can sidestep the problem by creating a dictionary with appropriate names

e.g.

```
myFunctionMap = {
  "2G_Functions" : { ... },
  "3G_Functions" : { ... },
}

for (name, functions) in myFunctionMap.iteritems():
  print name
  for func in functions.keys():
    print func
```

Comment: You can surely, as seen in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732955/python-how-to-get-arguments-name-runtime/16733435?noredirect=1#16733435).

Comment: @Developer yes, it's possible, but not by traversing the stack - you'd need to iterate over all objects like goodside suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the pessimism of the other answers, in this particular case you actually can do what you're asking for if there are no other names names assigned to the objects identified by `G2_Functions` and `G3_Functions` (I took the liberty of fixing your names, which are not valid Python identifiers as given.) That being said, this is a terrible, *terrible*, **terrible** idea and you should not do it, because it will eventually break and you'll be sad. So don't do it. **Ever.**

The following is analogous to what you're trying to do:

```
alpha = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
beta = {'c': 2, 'd': 4}
gamma = [alpha, beta]
listOfDefinedLocals = list(locals().iteritems())
for x, y in listOfDefinedLocals:
    if y is gamma[0]: print "gamma[0] was originally named " + x
    if y is gamma[1]: print "gamma[1] was originally named " + x
```

This will output:

```
gamma[1] was originally named beta 
gamma[0] was originally named alpha
```

I accept no responsibility for what you do with this information. It's pretty much guaranteed to fail exactly when you need it. I'm not kidding.

Comment: Why this is very likely to fail and not recommended ? Can you give me a scenario?

Comment: It's hard to give an example without a broader picture of why you're trying to do this at all, but in general this will give you strange behavior if other names are assigned to the objects `alpha` or `beta` (even if indirectly by assigning using elements of `gamma`) or if `alpha` or `beta` are reassigned to something else. Also, things like this result in code that's hard to read. Python is a language for writing *explicit* code with *obvious* behavior. If you want to do magic tricks, consider switching to Ruby or Perl. They're much better at them.

Comment: @goodside - +1, you're right, its possible :) Here's a oneliner to catch all possible variable names, assuming the gc is tracking them: `def varnames(val): print frozenset().union(*[set(k for (k,v) in d.iteritems() if v is val) for d in gc.get_referrers(y) if type(d) == dict])`

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.

In longer, it is sort of possible if you poke deep into, I think, the `gc` module (for the general case) or use `locals()` and `globals()`… But it's likely a better idea to simply define the list like this:

```
myFunctionMap = [ ("someName", someName), … ]
for name, map in myFunctionMap:
    print name
    …
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your list of lists as a list of strings instead:

```
d2G_Functions={'2G_1':"2G_f1",'2G_2':"2G_f2"}
d3G_Functions={'3G_1':"3G_f1",'3G_2':"3G_f2"}
myFunctions=["2G_Functions","3G_Functions"]

for dict_name in myFunctions:
    print dict_name
    the_dict = eval("d"+dict_name)
    for j in the_dict:
        print str(j)
```

(I changed the name of your original variables since python identifiers cannot begin with a digit)