# Retrieve the names of the object of a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of vectors

```
vector1=[1,1]
vector2=[2,2]
favoritevector=[1,-1]
```

Then a list of those vectors

```
vectors=[]
vectors.append(vector1)
vectors.append(vector2)
vectors.append(favoritevector)

vector
>>vector = [[1,1], [2,2], [1,-1]]
```

How can I retrieve the names of the objects inside the list vectors, instead of the actual value of the objects.

In this case, I would like to something that if I ask for the  element 0 of the list vectors the function or command returns to me the name "vector1" instead of [1,-1].

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting Python variable name in runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168391/getting-python-variable-name-in-runtime)

Comment: Based on the final result you want, you should probably rethink how you are trying to work this all out, and instead make use of dictionaries. Using a dictionary you can do: `vectors = {'vector1': [1,2], 'vector2' : [3, 4]}`. Then all you need to do to get the vector you want is: `vectors.get('vector1')`. Ultimately, instead of trying to get the name of the variable you are storing each of these vectors, just use a dictionary to store everything from the get go.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this using a list. You might try something like this:

```
class vector(object):
    def __init__(self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return """<vector {} {}>""".format(self.name, (self.x, self.y))
```

Then, you can do:

```
vectors = []
vectors.append(vector(name="vector1", x=1, y=2))
vectors.append(vector(name="vector2", x=2, y=3))
# to get the name of the first vector, do:
vectors[0].name
# 'vector1'
```

Comment: Thanks oliver. With classes is much easier and convenient, but I was asked explicity not to use classes... so.
I am glad to know that what I intended to do is not possible, were going crazy readind and watching tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the vectors is not important you can use dictionaries

```
vectors_dict["vector1"] = [1, 1]
```